# Who wins when placing a UITapGestureRecognizer above a UIButton?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I place a transparent `UIView` on top of my UI to detect tap gestures. I also have in my UI a few `UIButton`s which need to remain active.

Will the `UIButton` underneath the transparent view be in conflict with the `UITapGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: Best way is to try it yourself, IMHO.

Comment: If you place a view in front of another view then it will intercept touches. You can subclass UIView and intercept `-(id)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to pass touches to another element.

Comment: @Mazyod I did try it but I never managed that the button wins over the TapRecognizer (See my own answer). So it looks like I'll have to defien a view, where the Tap Gesture Recognizer will be active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried all the options for my TapRegocnizer and this is the conclusion:

```
C B E  
       Recognizer and Buttons react
    x  Recognizer and Buttons react
  x    Only Recognizer works
  x x  Only Recognizer works
x      Only Recognizer works
x   x  Only Recognizer works
x x    Only Recognizer works
x x x  Only Recognizer works

Legend:
C: Canceled in View
B: Delayed Begin
D: Delayed End
```

It looks like the the TapRecognizer is always triggered even if a Button underneath it. The Button will be activated if neither the `Canceled in View` nor `Delayed Begin` options are set. So to answer my question the button never wins over the TapRecognizer.

Comment: Do u place the button upon the transparent view or under the transparent view?